# Getting an error message, when trying to compile sass file with node.js

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass, compilation

I have tried to compile sass file for the first time, but I run into a problem. When I set up node.js, created json file and tried to compile it in cmd with : "npm run sass" I get the error message listed below.

I did everything to understand the error, but its too much for me. Can anyone of you please try to explain me, what the error is saying and how to solve it?

JSON file

```
{
  "name": "natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "lading page for natours",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css"
  },
  "author": "Pavel",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

The error message it creates, when I try to npm run sass.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Programovani\web\node-sass\bin\node-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)   
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! natours@1.0.0 sass: `node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the natours@1.0.0 sass script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you try to reformulate this as a question?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Have you installed node sass globally?

Comment: I have it installed locally via node.js.